# How to replace a part of Vec with a slice?

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<f32>` like this:

```
let mut v: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
v.push(1.0);
v.push(2.0);
v.push(3.0);
```

Is there an idiomatic way to replace a portion of the contents with a slice? I have a function like this:

```
fn replace(&mut v: Vec<f32>, start: usize, vals: &[f32]) {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, I'd like to replace the values in `v` with values from `vals`, starting from the index `start` of `v`. If I have the aforementioned `Vec`, I'd like to do this:

```
// Before v contains (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
replace(&v, 0, &[4.0, 5.0]);
// Now v would contain (4.0, 5.0, 3.0)
```

I guess this could be done by iterating starting from the `start` index, but is there a more idiomatic Rust way of doing this?

Comment: [`Vec::splice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice) ?

Comment: Specifically: `let mut v = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0]; v.splice(0..2, [4.0, 5.0].iter().cloned());`

Comment: @Shepmaster The duplicate is about _inserting_ multiple elements into a vector, while this question is about _replacing_ multiple elements.  Do you really think that's the same question?  I don't think so, even though the answers to these questions are similar.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate (or at least not a duplicate of the question you linked), even if the answer to the other question happens to cover both use cases.

Comment: user4815162342 is correct — the *question* is not an exact duplicate, but the *answer* is. The targeted question is actually a slightly broader interpretation of this question. You've helped out the site by providing a unique set of keywords that will point future visitors to to canonical answer — remember that **duplicates are not a bad thing**!  Think of it this way: "how do I add 1 and 1" is not a duplicate of "how do I add 2 and 9", but they'd both be a duplicate of "how do I add two integers"; the equivalent is true here.

Comment: @Shepmaster Fair enough.